# Enhancement by adaptive wavelet shrinkage denoising

Tags: image-processing, denoising, enhancement

I was wondering does anyone know any programming library or a way that can help me implement this algorithm.

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you have a link to a reference?

Comment: I have added the second hand and the original references, apparently [Introduction to Medical Image Processing](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b95041/biomedical/12_21_MIP2010.pdf) and papers by Andrew Laine and co-authors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cropped image stems from slides named: [Introduction to Medical Image Processing](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Eb95041/biomedical/12_21_MIP2010.pdf). It illustrates to me edges emphasis and/or contrast enhancement (unsharp masking) by non-linear coefficient weighting in appropriate wavelet domains.
I would retrace the mammographic image and  enhanced versions  in papers by Andrew Laine and co-authors, like [Enhancement by Multiscale Nonlinear Operators](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA314289.pdf) (Andrew Laine, Walter Huda, in Handbook of Medical Imaging, 2000), [Contrast Enhancement by Multiscale and Nonlinear Operators](https://academiccommons.columbia.edu/doi/10.7916/D8028ZBT/download) (J. Fan and A. Laine, 1996) [Figure 7.14: (a) Oringinal mammogram image M73. (b) Nonlinear enhancement with adaptive wavelet shrinkage denoising]:
[image: Image M73, mammogram]

The bottom plot is unknown to me. I don't have the knowledge of such codes  shared by the authors. There is a recent code called [Wavelet Unsharp-Mask and Clarity](https://github.com/Beep6581/RawTherapee/issues/2982). You might look for "homomorphic wavelet filtering" that could provide similar results.

Comment: This answer has been of much help. Thanks.